Find a vector field $\vec A$ such that $\nabla\times\vec A=\frac1{r^3}\vec r$ holds true in an appropriate region.
Find a vector field $\vec A$ such that $\nabla\times\vec A=\frac1{r^3}\vec r$ holds true in an appropriate region.
I have tried to take some special value, to make this equation true. Assume that $\vec A=(P,Q,R)$, then I think there should be $Px+Qy+Rz=0$, by some integral method.
But so far I still haven't solved this problem.
Thanks @KurtG. finding this solution. I want to know the case that $R\neq 0$.

It would be interesting to hear more about that integral method. The solution is well known. Spoiler.

@KurtG. Nothing special, just integrate both sides of the equation. But I don't think it's necessary and sufficient conditions.

An important point is that $\vec A$ has a necessary singularity not only in $0$ but also on an infinite ray that starts there (Dirac string). Edit & correction: the known solution does satisfy $Px+Qx+Rz=0,.$

This question is a duplicate of: Finding a vector field such that its curl equals a given vector field.

Typo: does satisfy $Px+Qy+Rz=0,.$

@KurtG. We want to avoid this normal case. Can we let $R\neq 0$?

You can achieve this by adding to $\vec A$ a field $\vec B$ that has curl zero.
